# rails_digest caching per user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, digest

I my app, my views are generated according to users actions and rights.

I would like to implement rails_digest to cache my pages but I need to do this per user.

I know it's possible in fragment cache:

```
<% cache "mypage", project, user %>
```

But this doesn't seem to work in rails_digest.

Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

I found the way to do it:

just write: <% cache [user, project] do %> ... <% end %>

When something changes in the project, all you need to do is project.touch. The cache will be reset for everyone.